# C Drawing overlay WINAPI

Tags: c, winapi, drawing, overlay

I'm looking for a way to draw an overlay. I want to create a small popup box in the bottom right corner to notify the user. I'm not sure what they are called, but I guess it's kinda like an overlay? I guess the easiest way to do this for me is in the winapi, but I'm not sure how. Anyone has a link I can read with more info, or maybe even code samples? Even the name of these notifications boxes would help so I can google better.

Thanks

Comment: A *balloon notification*? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @AlexK. No, not really, more the msn style notification

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it might help but you can try with sprite layers

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb194908.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these notifications are simply small windows with the WS_EX_TOPMOST style and an effect such as those provided by [AnimateWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Or if you don't want to do that much customization, maybe you can settle for a balloon tip from [classic notification icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).